# How to format stack trace logs on stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I am trying to share a stack trace on a question that I am asking on stack overflow. Looking around, I found these suggestions:

- Indent the text with four spaces, but this didn't work.
- Include the whole stack trace in ``...`` block. This worked, but now each line was on its own, and it looked real ugly.

Obviously, others are already doing this, but when I try to research for it, I am not getting any useful tips.

**Edit:** I saw the comment about using `<pre>..</pre>` tags, and I tried them for the stack trace on my other question, and this was exactly what I was looking for. I was using `<code>..</code>` before, but that didn't work as nicely (probably due to the fact that the stack trace is not really a code snippet in an actual programming language).

**Edit2:** I found out what was wrong with my previous tests with four leading spaces. According to the documentation, the code block has to be preceded by an empty line, but I didn't have such an empty line.

Comment: You can put the text of the stack trace in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: *"Indent the text with four spaces, but this didn't work."* Then you did something wrong. Using 4 spaces works, also for stacktraces.